# CSS3 Slideshow: How to display a text for each image?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on a slideshow in CSS3 and I would like display a text for each of my images. I use this example: http://www.creativejuiz.fr/trytotry/juizy-slideshow-full-css3-html5/, but I don't use exactly the same code, because mine is responsive.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <div id="slideshow-container">
        <div id="slider">
            <figure>
                <img src="images/image-1.jpg" alt="">
                <figcaption>Style 1</figcaption>
            </figure>
            <figure>
                <img src="images/image-2.jpg" alt="">
                <figcaption>Style 2</figcaption>
            </figure>
            <figure>
                <img src="images/image-3.jpg" alt="">
                <figcaption>Style 3</figcaption>
            </figure>
            <figure>
                <img src="images/image-4.jpg" alt="">
                <figcaption>Style 4</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
        <span id="timeline"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
/* SLIDESHOW */

#slideshow
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 75%;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 1px 7px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 1px 7px;
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 1px 7px;
}

#slideshow-container
{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#slider
{
    position: relative;
    width: 500%;
    animation: 32s slider infinite;
    -webkit-animation: 32s slider infinite;
    -moz-animation: 32s slider infinite;
    -o-animation: 32s slider infinite;
}

#slider figure
{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
}

#slider img
{
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}

#slideshow figcaption
{
    position:absolute;
    padding: 20px 20px; margin:0;
    left:0; right:0; bottom: 5px;
    text-align:center;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    word-spacing: 0.05em;
    font-family: Georgia, Times, serif;
    background: #000;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(225,225,225);
    color: #555;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.3);

    -webkit-animation: figcaptionner 32s infinite;
    -moz-animation: figcaptionner 32s infinite;
    animation: figcaptionner 32s infinite;
}

/* Slider animation */

@keyframes slider
{
    0%
    {
        left: 0;
    }

    20%
    {
        left: 0;
    }

    25%
    {
        left: -100%;
    }

    45%
    {
        left: -100%;
    }

    50%
    {
        left: -200%;
    }

    70%
    {
        left: -200%;
    }

    75%
    {
        left: -300%;
    }

    95%
    {
        left: -300%;
    }

    100%
    {
        left: 0%;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slider
{
    0%
    {
        left: 0;
    }

    20%
    {
        left: 0;
    }

    25%
    {
        left: -100%;
    }

    45%
    {
        left: -100%;
    }

    50%
    {
        left: -200%;
    }

    70%
    {
        left: -200%;
    }

    75%
    {
        left: -300%;
    }

    95%
    {
        left: -300%;
    }

    100%
    {
        left: 0%;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes slider
{
    0%
    {
        left: 0;
    }

    20%
    {
        left: 0;
    }

    25%
    {
        left: -100%;
    }

    45%
    {
        left: -100%;
    }

    50%
    {
        left: -200%;
    }

    70%
    {
        left: -200%;
    }

    75%
    {
        left: -300%;
    }

    95%
    {
        left: -300%;
    }

    100%
    {
        left: 0%;
    }
}

@-o-keyframes slider
{
    0%
    {
        left: 0;
    }

    20%
    {
        left: 0;
    }

    25%
    {
        left: -100%;
    }

    45%
    {
        left: -100%;
    }

    50%
    {
        left: -200%;
    }

    70%
    {
        left: -200%;
    }

    75%
    {
        left: -300%;
    }

    95%
    {
        left: -300%;
    }

    100%
    {
        left: 0%;
    }
}

/* TIMELINE */

#timeline
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgb(214, 98, 13);
    height: 2px;
    animation: timeliner 32s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: timeliner 32s infinite;
    -moz-animation: timeliner 32s infinite;
    -o-animation: timeliner 32s infinite;
}

/* Timeline animation */

@keyframes timeliner
{
    0%, 25%, 50%, 75%, 100%
    {
        width: 0;
    }

    20%, 45%, 70%, 95%
    {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes timeliner
{
    0%, 25%, 50%, 75%, 100%
    {
        width: 0;
    }

    20%, 45%, 70%, 95%
    {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes timeliner
{
    0%, 25%, 50%, 75%, 100%
    {
        width: 0;
    }

    20%, 45%, 70%, 95%
    {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

@-o-keyframes timeliner
{
    0%, 25%, 50%, 75%, 100%
    {
        width: 0;
    }

    20%, 45%, 70%, 95%
    {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

The result without the addition of the figcaption tags: http://nextgenfocus.com/slideshow/

I'd like to bring up a text for each of my images, but I don't know how.

Here the result with the figcaption tags: nextgenfocus.com/slideshow2

I added this:

```
#slider figcaption
{
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(225, 225, 225);
    color: #555;
}
```

but the text does not appear.

Thank you if you find a solution.

Comment: I just downloaded your script and reproduced the code and it is working and showing the text on my end, only that the images are distorted. Can you give us more details or a demo of what you have achieve so far so that we may help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is into the `float: left` on images which makes your `<figure>` height to be zero. Move the `width: 20%` and the `float: left` to the `<figure>` and change the images to `width: 100%`. It will do the trick.

```
#slider figure
{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}

#slider img
{
   width:100%;
}
```

Here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5xhadj4j/).

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, dude! It helped me a lot for my experience.

Comment: Glad to help! Have CSS fun!